# Applescript print by selecting preset and format

Tags: printing, automation, applescript

I am trying to define the print parameters as presets with AppleScript.
I managed to open the pdf file with acrobat, open the print panel and define the number of copies, but then I was unable to "click" on the "Stampante..." (image 1) and subsequent (image 2) buttons. I do not find what are the commands to act on the window. Do you have any suggestions

```
#apro file con acrobat
#definire posizione la prima volta del programma
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
    activate application
    #apro file creare percorso per file su temp 
    open file "giungete:users:corrado:desktop:201.188_001.pdf"
    #uso pulsanti per eseguire comando
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "201.188_001.pdf"
            #apro stampa
            keystroke "p" using command down
            delay 1
            #vado copie
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1
            #definisco copie
            keystroke "120"
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
            delay 0.1   
            #do invio
            #keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzFw4.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cpyD.png)

Comment: You might take a look at these questions/answers as they discuss methods of accessing various UI elements. They should give you some ideas. [Selecting Pop Up Menu Buttons in AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549556/selecting-pop-up-menu-buttons-in-applescript), [AppleScript -- Menu Item in the Menu Button popup …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573300/applescript-menu-item-in-the-menu-button-popup-is-not-selectable-while-using/67577736#67577736)

Comment: Mockman's 2nd link/hint leads to : __ > click button "Stampante" of window "Stampa" of application process "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC" of application "System Events" < __ Further you can replace your "tab"s with: __ > click text field 1 of window "Stampa" of …[et.] < __ Then you can go on with: __ > click pop up button 2 of window "Stampa" …[etc.] < __ …and: __ > click menu item "b/n" of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of window"Stampa"  …[etc.] < __ Repeat with "pop up button 3" and "menu item "Layout"". –– My explicit "answer" was voted down without comment so it's deleted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey**  with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **Italiano — principale** and **Inglese (US)** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Assuming you are Italian, and with no disrespect intended, I am not sure how well you will understand my answer or why I coded the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in the manner I have, however, I will try to explain some of it.

If you have a *document* opened in **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC** and you bring up the **Print** *dialog box*, it is a *modal window* and as such can simply be addressed as `window 1` and no need to necessarily use `window "Print"` in general. The same goes for e.g. `window "201.188_001.pdf"`, it can simply be addressed as `window 1`, but to just print an opened *document* the *document window* does not need to be relevant in my *example* **AppleScript** *code* because of how it is coded.

As there are multiple `pop up button` being clicked on the second |Print| *window* I wrapped the *code* in a *handler* so they can be clicked by `number` or `name` and `number` or `name` of the `menu item`. Keep in mind that by `number` the *menu separators* count as an incremented `number`.

I am using a `choose file` *command* to select the target **PDF** *document* to open and print in **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**. You can of course choose not to use it and just set the `print thisFile` *command* to e.g.: `print file "giungete:users:corrado:desktop:201.188_001.pdf"`

I have added *comments* through the *example* **AppleScript** *code* to help explain what is happening.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
property |Copies| : "120"
property |Print| : "Stampa"
property |Show Details| : "Mostra dettagli"

set thisFile to ¬
    choose file of type "com.adobe.pdf" with prompt ¬
        "Choose a PDF document:" default location ¬
        (path to documents folder) without invisibles

tell application id "com.adobe.Reader"
    activate
    ignoring application responses
        print thisFile
    end ignoring
end tell

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    tell window 1 of application process "AdobeReader"
        
        --  ## First |Print| window. ##
        
        repeat until its name is |Print|
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        
        --  # Set the number of copies to print.
        
        set value of first text field of group 1 to |Copies|
        
        --  # Clicking the |Printer...| button  causes a
        --  # ~5 second delay, therefore tab to it instead.
        --  # Tested in macOS Monterey and it took 18 tabs
        --  # from the default opening of the |Print| window,
        --  # however, it needs to be checked manually in
        --  # other versions of macOS first.                
        
        repeat 18 times
            key code 48 --  # tab key
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        key code 36 --  # enter key
        
        --  # Wait a moment for the second |Print| window.
        
        delay 1
        
        --  ## Second |Print| window. ##
        
        --  # Make sure second |Print| window is expanded.
        
        if (the name of its button 2) is |Show Details| then
            click button 2
            delay 1
        end if
        
        --  # Click and select on Preset:
        
        my clickPopUpButtonMenuItem(2, 1)
        
        delay 0.25
        
        --  # Click and select on Layout:
        
        my clickPopUpButtonMenuItem(3, 1)
        
        delay 0.25
        
        -- # Click the Print button on the second |Print| window.
        
        click button 4
        
        delay 0.25
        
        --  ## First |Print| window. ##
        
        --  # Click the Print button on the first |Print| window.
        --  # Leave commented until testing is finished.
        
        --click button 4
        
    end tell
end tell


--  # Handler #

on clickPopUpButtonMenuItem(PopUpButton, MenuItem)
    --  # PopUpButton - Can be either an integer or the name.
    --  # MenuItem - Can be either an integer or the name.
    --  # MenuItem - Menu separators count as an incremented number.
    tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
        tell window 1 of application process "AdobeReader"
            click pop up button PopUpButton
            click menu item MenuItem of menu 1 of pop up button PopUpButton
        end tell
    end tell
end clickPopUpButtonMenuItem
```

---

**Notes:**

As previously mentioned I chose not to *click* the **Printer...** (Stampante...) *button* because of the ~5 second delay if clicked. I believe the delay is caused because the second `|Print|` *window* opens and it has to time out because the *button* clicked it is from the first `|Print|` *window* which is now actually `window 2`, not `window 1`, and this is why *tabbing* makes more sense to avoid the delay.

I also tested the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **macOS Catalina** and it was 17 *tab stops* to the **Printer...**  (Stampante...) *button*, not 18 like in **macOS Monterey**.

Keep in mind that the number of *tabs* will be different if you change any of the other setting in the first `|Print|` *window* and it was based on your "image 1" link in that the only default you changed was the number of copies. You can always choose to click the **Printer...** (Stampante...) *button* instead and wait the ~5 second delay. It would be `click button 2` instead of the `repeat` *loop*.

**UI Scripting** is *kludgy* and prone to failure and can break easily from one version of **macOS** to another as **Apple** and **developers** continually changes things, e.g. the *hierarchical UI element structure*. Case in point, 17 *tabs* in **macOS Catalina** vs. 18 *tabs* in **macOS Monterey** in this particular use case, the first `|Print|` *window* in **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**.

---

**Add-on to address request in comment**

Even though the question originally focused on **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**, nonetheless, as the author of the OP asked in comments about doing it in **Preview**, here is some *example* **AppleScript** *code* for use in **macOS Monterey** and **Preview**.

I thought it would be an interesting contrast to the different *hierarchical UI element structure* of the **Print** *dialog box* between the two *applications* to under the same version of **macOS** and how fragile **UI Scripting** can be preforming the same basic task between two different *applications*. While this would work with **Preview** in **macOS Big Sur** and **macOS Monterey**, it will not in **macOS Catalina** as the *hierarchical UI element structure* for the **Print** *dialog box* differs slightly, as there is no `splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1`.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Example AppleScript code for use in macOS Monterey and Preview.

property |Copies| : "120"
property |Print| : "Stampa"
property |Show Details| : "Mostra dettagli"

set thisFile to ¬
    choose file of type "com.adobe.pdf" with prompt ¬
        "Choose a PDF document:" default location ¬
        (path to documents folder) without invisibles

tell application id "com.apple.Preview"
    activate
    open thisFile
end tell

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
    -- launch --    # Used in an attemp to workaround a bug.
    
    --  # Used to see the full large print dialog if Preview opens
    --  # the document too tight on the left side of the screen.
    
    tell window 1 of application process "Preview"
        set currentPosition to its position
        if item 1 of currentPosition is less than 70 then ¬
            set its position to {70, item 2 of currentPosition}
    end tell
    
    --  # Bring up the Print dialog box.
    
    keystroke "p" using command down
    
    --  # Wait until the Print dialog box is ready.
    
    repeat until exists button 1 of ¬
        splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of ¬
        application process "Preview"
    end repeat
    
    tell splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"
        
        --  # Show Details if necessary. (Mostra dettagli)
        
        if exists button |Show Details| then
            click button |Show Details|
            delay 1
        end if
        
        --  # Printer: pop up button. (Stampante:)
        
        click pop up button 1
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 1
        
        --  # Preset: pop up button.
        
        click pop up button 2
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 2
        
        --  # Copies: text field. (Copie:)
        
        set value of text field 1 to |Copies|
        
        --  # Paper Size: pop up button. (Dimensioni pagina:)
        
        click pop up button 3
        click menu item 5 of menu 1 of pop up button 3
        click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item 5 of menu 1 of pop up button 3
        
        --  # Preview pop up button (By default.) (Anteprima)
        
        click pop up button 4
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 4
        
        delay 1
        
        --  # The following will vary based on menu selection of  pop up button 4.
        
        tell group 3
            click pop up button 1
            click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 1
            -- click pop up button 2
            -- click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 2
            -- click pop up button 3
            -- click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 3
        end tell
        
        --  # Print button. (Stampa)
        
        -- click button 4 --    # Or click by name.
        click button |Print|
        
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: What a nice job you did! I studied it and I learned a lot. The tab to get to the second "Print" is really delicate. I had to put 16 with Monterey. I needed that the print window remains open so that other parameters are editable if it is needed even if the presets should be what it serves. I don't have the printer yet to see what other menus owns but the operation is very clear.

Comment: I noticed that the number of copying by changing the preset return to 1 and do not pass from the first to the second Print so I married under the definition
I learned that the lines in the menus make counter !!!
Until here with the modifies to your code everything works as I want.

Comment: I then thought of using Preview in which you immediately arrive at the second "Print" but I immediately came across the usual mistake. I assure you that I worked all afternoon !!! I modified where there was adobereader with preview, removed the first part but when I arrive at "click pop up button" the error comes out. What suggestions you have to give me thanks corrado

Comment: @Corrado Polentes, RE: "I don't have the printer" - If you do to have the printer yet, then doing this is a moot point as the **Print** _dialog boxes_ will change based on the selected **Printer**. Also as I previously stated **UI Scripting** is _kludgy_ and prone to failure. As far as doing it in **Preview**, I consider that a separate question entirely as the _code_ in your question explicitly stated `tell application "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"` - RE: "The tab to get to the second "Print" is really delicate. I had to put 16 with Monterey." -- This is going to changed based on the **Printer**.

Comment: @Corrado Polentes, Also keep in mind that the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ is just that, an example. It is not necessarily meant to be _turn key_ and requires adaptation for ones specific needs. There are many things that can be coded that work regardless, however **UI Scripting** can very much be on a _case by case basis_ and _one size does not fit all_ as the saying goes. In other words, you can not just swap out the _name_ of the target _application_ and expect it to work in every use case. In **Preview**, the **Print** _dialog box_ has a different _hierarchical UI element structure_.

Comment: @Corrado Polentes, Here is some _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ for use in **macOS Monterey** and **Preview**: [https://paste.ee/p/bUuZU](https://paste.ee/p/bUuZU) (The previous link expired.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this new job. I see that it is very different from the previous one I would never have arrived. now I look how it works thanks again

Comment: @Corrado Polentes, as the link to the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ for **Preview** in **macOS Monterey** is going to expire, I added it to this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have successfully ending the impetation of your code for Acrobat Reader but when I have a little time I will try to use that preview. I would also like to write something about how to manage these panels that have as you wrote you infinite variations. I used the script in FileMaker where I manage presets, formats, printer and copies, came a nice job, thanks again